# IDE errors JDBC java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying JDBC with a java program I'm trying to write, but my IDE is giving me some errors.  I was wondering if someone could help me out.  I added the SQL driver to the CLASSPATH and here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Employee {
    public int checkEmpID(int empID) throws SQLException, IOException {
        int employeeID = empID;
        int found = 0;

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("-","-","-");

        String stmt1 = "select Enumber from Employee where Enumber = ?";
        PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(stmt1);
        p.clearParameters();
        p.setInteger(1, employeeID);
        ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();
        while(r.next())
            found = r.getInteger(1);
        return found;
    }
}
```

The errors I get are 2:

"cannot find symbol" "symbol:  method setInteger(int,int)   location:  interface java.sql.PreparedStatement  p.setInteger(1, employeeID);"

and

"cannot find symbol" "symbol:  method getInteger(int)   location:  interface java.sql.ResultSet  found = r.getInteger(1);"

Comment: How about setInt rather than setInteger

Comment: I recomment do learn how to find and read javadocs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods are [setInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) and [getInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

The methods should be [`setInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) and [`getInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29).